# Nswag Typescript API client InjectionToken is not being resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm using Nswag to generate an API client for an external asp.net core service. In this generated client I have

```
export const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');
```

I want to resolve this.

In my app.module.ts I added.

```
providers: [
  AuthGuardService,
  AuthService,
  {
    provide: GeneratedAPIClient.API_BASE_URL,
    useValue: environment.API_BASE_URL
  }
]
```

In the constructor of my AuthService I'm trying to use this API Client like this.

```
constructor(
  private router: Router, 
  private http: HttpClient) {
    const client = new GeneratedAPIClient.AccountClient(this.http);

    client.userinfo().subscribe((userInfoData) => {
         // stuff
    });
}
```

In environment.ts I have

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:5000'
};
```

when running the application with `ng serve` the API always uses the base address for the angular project, that is `http://localhost:4200` and not what I have in the `environment.ts` file.

What have I missed?

UPDATE: Clarification: I have a separate asp.Net core API that I am trying to access from Angular. The separate API is on port 5000. Angular is on port 4200. So I am not looking to change angulars port.

Answer (score 1):

We use nswag in our project at work, but typically inject all of our generated "clients" rather than newing them up. If the `AccountClient` is anything like ours, it will expect an `HttpClient` in the constructor as well as a BASE_URL.

(For reference, here is what the constructor looks like of one of our generated clients):

```
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) 
baseUrl?: string) {
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "http://localhost:61350";
}
```

Another thing, and the reason is escaping me at the moment, but went the useFactory route on our base_url_provider, so it looks more like this:

```
{
    provide: API_BASE_URL,
    useFactory: () => {
        return `${environment.API_BASE_URL}`;
    }
}
```

I think the way you're doing it is fine, though.

Anyway, hope that helps. If it still doesn't work, could you post the code of the generated AccountClient?

### EDIT

Now that I re-read the question, the answer above about port number might be what you're looking for.

Comment: No, you are correct, I was unclear in what I meant. I want to access a separate API that is hosted from another application (asp.net core), that application is on port 5000. Angular is on port 4200.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I figured out what I was missing. Posted it as an answer for others.

Comment: If you do: this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "http://localhost:61350"; then you will lose this value everytime the client is generated again, the idea of injecting the API_BASE_URL, is to get the value from injection. The "baseUrl" parameter is always null like if the injection is not working, the provider configuration seems to be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to just import environment variables to the component where you need to use them in, in this case a service, your AuthService:

`import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';`

and then use it there:

```
this.http.get(environment.API_BASE_URL + ...).subscribe(...);
```

It's a little more troublesome because you need to import into all components where it's used, but on the upside you don't need to inject it globally.

Comment: I was unclear in the question. I want angular to access an external API with a generated nswag client. The API is on another port and is separate to Angular

Comment: Ok, then you're doing it the correct way, as you might already know, you can use environment.prod.ts to place your API url for published site.

Comment: I'll try it but I would really like to not have to do anything with the base url at all (besides setting up the provider). My understanding is that the point of the InjectionToken is that it happens in the background without me doing anything special when I want to use the service.

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing that I needed to add the client as a provider, and then could inject the entire thing with the proper urls.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with the help of the two answers, but there was still a piece of the puzzle missing..

My provider in `app.module.ts` now looks like this.

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: GeneratedAPIClient.API_BASE_URL, // <-- this is still here
      useValue: environment.API_BASE_URL
    },
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthService,
    GeneratedAPIClient.AccountClient // <-- note this addition.
  ],
```

Once the above addition was made I could do this in a constructor.

```
constructor(@Inject(GeneratedAPIClient.AccountClient) client: GeneratedAPIClient.AccountClient) { }
```

Now I get an instance of the client, and when injected in this way the client also gets the `API_BASE_URL` set to the proper url.